# Дієслово недоконаного виду для "придбати"

Tags: переклад, дієслова, conjugation

В російській мові "приобрести" (док.) - "приобретать" (недок.)

В українській "придбати" (док.) - ???

Будь ласка, якщо це можливо, надайте у відповіді посилання на лексикографічні джерела (словники), що фіксують відповідне дієслово.

Comment: [Набувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nabuvaty) 1. Ставати власником 2. Набирати чого-небудь, здобувати щось (про ознаку, якість і т. ін.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Придбавати*** є граматично правильною формою, разом із усіма її відмінюваннями як-то *придбаваю, придбаваєш, придбаває, придбаваємо, придбавають*.

1. Власне, назва статті на СУМ-11 — [*придбавати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/prydbavaty).

   > *Під час екскурсій школярі, як правило, збирають багатий матеріал для майбутніх тематичних вечорів, **придбавають** репродукції окремих картин* — Мистецтво, 1, 1969, 37);

   Щоправда, багато хто критикує СУМ за занадто велику кількість русизмів, які прийшли до української під час совєцької окупації.
2. Тому ось поважне джерело: **Словник Грінченка** (Словарь украинского языка, Кіевъ, 1909, т. 3):

   > [***Придбавати***](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/47444-prydbavaty.html#show_point), -ва́ю, -єш, сов. в. придба́ти, -ба́ю, -єш, гл. Пріобрѣтать, пріобрѣсть.
   >   *Се **придбавають** у Бога собі ласки, даючи милостину.* — Волч. у.
3. У Грінченка також є такий варіант:

   > [***Приобріти***](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/47927-pryobrity.html#show_point), -рію, -єш, гл. = придбати.

   Напевно, мається також на увазі недоконана форма *приобрівати*, але я не знайшов свідчень на продовження цієї думки.
4. Словопедія [містить](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53407/271606.html) кілька синонімів слова *придбавати*, але варто зауважити, що усі вони не є повними синонімами. Наприклад, не підходять варіанти виду *«купувати»*, тому що, з юридичної точки зору, «придбання» може бути не лише методом купівлі (подарунок, спадщина тощо).

---

#### Чтиво

- [Отут](http://ua-mova.livejournal.com/1170536.html) кілька користувачів обіцяли «зʼїсти власну шляпу», якщо хтось надасть посилання на поважний словник, який містить слово «придбавати». :)

Comment: Треба пошукати підтвердження, але з практики можу сказати, що *придбавати* і *купувати* - це дійсно синоніми в юридичному розумінні в Україні. А більш загальне слово - *набуття* (права власності) як в результатіі  купівлі(придбання), дарування,  за спадщиною, так і з інших підстав.

Comment: [ЦКУ](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/T030435.html). Ст. 118.ч.2. "Господарське товариство, яке *придбало* або *іншим чином набуло* ...".  Ст. 195 ч.1 3) "похідні цінні папери, механізм розміщення та обігу яких пов'язаний з правом на *придбання* чи *продаж* ...". Ст. 362 ч.3 "Якщо бажання *придбати* частку у праві спільної часткової власності виявили кілька співвласників, продавець має право вибору *покупця*". [ГКУ](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/ed_2003_01_16/an/1391/T030436.html#1391). Ст. 251 ч.1  "*придбання* чи *набуття будь-яким іншим способом* у власність" тощо.